# Google maps not showing, HTML

Tags: javascript, css, html, google-maps

I'm currently working on an IP tracking program, but I have some problems with the google maps function, I can't get the map to show or put a marker on the IP location.
Can anyone point me in the right directions?

Here is the code I've used for the map, I took it from googles own website.

```
<div id="map"></div>

<script>
  var map;
  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 8
    });
  }
</script>

 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAnoX8LSgSg5-pRiF5_IzZ313VsNZzuo-4&callback=initMap"
 async defer></script>
```

[Here's my complete code:](https://pastebin.com/AM8afFHZ)

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mcve]. Code relevant to your problem belongs directly into your question (in text form & properly formatted), not just on an external site. Please edit accordingly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To show map you need to provide `height`.

Add this height in your style for div with id `map`

```
 #map {
     height: 300px;
 }
```

Update:

if map container  (with id map) should take up 100% of the height of the HTML body. Note that we must specifically declare those percentages for  and  as well.

```
 #map {
    height: 100%;
 }

 html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
 }
```

Comment: Great! you can read in google map documentation that height need to be set,otherwise map will not show in div.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, div was like

```
<div id="map" style="height: 100%; width: 100%"></div>
```

but map appeared only when I've add position: absolute property explicitly.
So, the result was

```
<div id="map" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; position: absolute"></div>
```

and it works.

Answer (score 1):

#### You didn't added the api key

Google Maps JavaScript API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys
mw.m @ util.js:220
util.js:220 Google Maps JavaScript API warning: InvalidKey https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#invalid-key

Comment: I have no clue why there was no API key in the pastebin, I have an API key in mine. Uploaded a new link that has my API key.

Comment: /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

add this styles in your html

[follow this pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/WfHTA1gQ)